# ExtJS Grid - how do I reference a store by id in my view

Tags: javascript, extjs, pagingtoolbar

I am trying to reference a store in my app for the purpose of adding a paging tool bar at the bottom of my gird.  In most examples I have studied the store is referenced by variable, ex: store: someStore.  However, by I have build my app a little differently and did create a reference variable to the store.  I have 
tried assigning an id but this did not work.

Here is what I have:

In my view Grid.js:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.user.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'user-grid'
    },
    bind: {
        store: '{users}',
    },
    columns: {...},

    //my paging tool bar
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        store: 'girdStore'
        //store: {users} -> did not work
    }],
    ...
});
```

In my view model GridModel.js:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.user.GridModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

    requires: [
        'myApp.model.User'
    ],

    stores: {
        users: {
            model: 'myApp.model.User',
            storeId: 'gridStore',
            autoLoad: true
        }
    },
    formulas: {...}
});
```

When I try to reference the {users} store by id 'gridStore' I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

What is the best way to proceed without completely refactoring my model?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a reference to your grid, you could get the store by calling the `getStore` function. See the [ExtJs 6.2.1 documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-getStore).

```
var grid; // reference to your grid
var store = grid.getStore();
```

---

You can create the store in `initComponent` and then attach it to the `dockedItems`, so both will share the same store.

```
initComponent: function () {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'myApp.model.User',
        storeId: 'gridStore',
        autoLoad: true
    });
    this.store = store;
    this.dockedItems = [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        store:store
    }];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

The `initComponent` is called once when a new instance of the class is created, see the [description in the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-initComponent).

> ...It is intended to be implemented by each subclass of
>   Ext.Component to provide any needed constructor logic. The
>   initComponent method of the class being created is called first, with
>   each initComponent method up the hierarchy to Ext.Component being
>   called thereafter. This makes it easy to implement and, if needed,
>   override the constructor logic of the Component at any step in the
>   hierarchy. The initComponent method must contain a call to callParent
>   in order to ensure that the parent class' initComponent method is also
>   called...

The view with the `initComponent` function.

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.user.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'user-grid'
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'myApp.model.User',
            storeId: 'gridStore',
            autoLoad: true
        });
        this.store = store;
        this.dockedItems = [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            store: store
        }];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    columns: {...},
    ...
});
```

Comment: Yes I do that in my controller to hookup the store to my view, but I am not sure how that helps me with referencing it in dockedItems.  Adding  bind: store: '{users}' } removed the error but it does not show any data as I add records via my addRecord method.

Comment: Ok apologies for the dumb question ( I am very new to EXTjs ), but where would this initComp method go?  As a method of the Ext.define('myApp.view.user.Grid', { }) class?

Comment: Right I see, but this has the same effect as simply adding  bind: store: '{users}' } to dockedItems [{...}]  It removes the TypeError, but my paging tool bar does not display the number of records or pages.  This problem might be unrelated to referencing the store correctly ...

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle with the problem?

Comment: Do not forget in your store the configs pageSize: 25 and  autoLoad:{             start: 0,
                limit: 25
            }, (25 is an example) http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.toolbar.Paging.html

Comment: I'll copy it on Sancha Fiddle...my company blocks JSFiddle :(